# How to parse a .eml file in php?

Tags: php, parsing, mime, eml

How to parse a [.eml](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/eml) file in php? Is there any PHP libriary or PHP extension ?

I want to display the mail header information such as sender, receiver, title, attachement and eml body content in browser.

Comment: That's not a question but a google request. - If you're looking for code: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/

Comment: I agree with Hakre, please explain what you've attempted to do so far..

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) is what I use:

```
composer require php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser
```

And then PHP:

```
$parser = new \PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
$emailFile = 'myEmailFile.eml';
$parser->setText(file_get_contents($emailFile));
```

Then, to get addresses:

```
$toAddressesQ = $parser->getAddresses('to');
```

Or the body:

```
$text = $parser->getMessageBody('text');
$html = $parser->getMessageBody('html');
```

Or the header:

```
$subject = $parser->getHeader('subject');
```

Or the attachments:

```
$attachments = $parser->getAttachments();
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to do it. One way is to simply do it yourself, it's not that complicated.

Otherwise, you might want to have a look at the Mailparse library:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php

And there is also this one:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

Comment: but even the php extension mailparse in php.net doesn't works well with some eml file.I can not get eml header information such as subject,time,sender　when the eml file source like this ------------Return-Path: <test@mail.com.cn>Delivered-To:aa@mail.com.cn*X-WM-Delivered:bb@mail.com.cn ....-------------
the is not blank line between erver item. so can not be parsed

Comment: At last I find a php libaray here 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html
but it doesn't work well.it can not parse eml file when the source of eml file header item does not have break line.

Comment: `Return-Path: <test@mail.com.cn>
 Delivered-To: test@mail.com.cn
 X-WM-Delivered: test@mail.com.cn
 Delivered-To: receive@mail.com.cn
 X-WM-Delivered: all@mail.com.cn
 Received: from PC-201104191348 ([211.154.169.179])
  (envelope-sender <test@mail.com.cn>)
  by 125.208.8.125 with ESMTP
  
 Date: Tue, 3 Jul 2012 12:28:16 +0800
 From: "test" <test@mail.com.cn   To: "all" <all@mail.com.cn   Cc: "bb" <bb@mail.com.cn>
 Subject: =?gb2312?B?ufq80s2zvMa+1jIwMTLE6jfUws+1zbPJ/by2z+7Ev82o1qo=?=  Message-ID: <201207031228157969470@mail.com.cn>
X-mailer: Foxmail 6, 15, 201, 23 [cn]
Mime-Version: 1.0`

Comment: There is a missing > here: "To: "all" <all@mail.com.cn "