# Yii2. How to render .eml in a view?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, eml

I have a `string` with an `.eml` message. How to render this email on the page of my site in some kind of frame?

Is there any composer extension, that could render `.eml` content as a regular mail app.

Comment: @JeremyHarris what should I try? I have a simple string with content of an `.eml` mesaage. I need to display it as regular mail app renders it on the page of my site. Simple `echo $mail` won't help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a .eml file in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409235/how-to-parse-a-eml-file-in-php)

Comment: @JeremyHarris thank you, but no. I need to **render**, not to *parse*. I just don't know what to search. Maybe I could use `<iframe>`, but not sure. I need help to understand, how rendering `.eml` message could be done.

Comment: You mean render it raw? You could just `echo(file_get_contents('test.eml'));` and spit out the file contents if thats all you wanted. If you want it formatted, you need to parse it first, THEN build the HTML/CSS around your data from the email. No silver bullet here I am afraid.

Comment: @JeremyHarris thank you for your answer. I was looking exact for a "silver bullet" (composer module/extension), that could take raw `.eml` message with headers and so on and give me HTML/CSS output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this extension](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser)

And snippet like this:

```
$parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
$parser->setText($message);

$html = $parser->getMessageBody('html');

echo $html;
```

`$html` is wrapped in my view into proper `<div>`'s.